# Catkin_make not update my saved python file

Tags: python, ros, catkin

So I was modifying a python executable in a ros package named my_turtlebot2_training. I saved the python file after modifying it. When I run catkin_make under ~/catkin_ws, all I got is:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/afrl/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/afrl/catkin_ws/build"
#### 
[  0%] Built target _theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RLExperimentInfo 
[ 14%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs 
[ 42%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_eus 
[ 71%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_py 
[100%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_lisp 
[100%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages_cpp 
[100%] Built target theconstruct_msgs_generate_messages
```

Which did not reflect any changes to my python file. I even tried modifying it to output an error, like adding `import sdfsdfasddgfk`, but catkin_make still does not output an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catkin_make` doesn't do any effect to python files. You must make your Python file executable by making `chmod +x your_python_file.py`

Then you can run `rosrun my_turtlebot2_training your_python_file.py`

Simply, since Python is an interpreted language, `catkin` does not compile Python files.